# Accessing DelegateListLink Property in Exchange Online?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

I need to give a couple of users ReadPermissions to some mailboxes. And I need the read-only mailboxes to appear in the users' Outlook via auto-mapping.

I know that you can achieve this via the mxExchDelegateListLink attribute in the Active Directory. However, this is not working with Office 365 and DirSync.

I figured out, that you can view the property in PowerShell using the following command:

```
(Get-MailboxPermission <mailbox> -ReadFromDomainController)[0].DelegateListLink
```

It lists all the users whose Outlook will automatically map the queried mailbox.

How can I add users to that attribute via PowerShell? This Property is the same for each MailboxPermission object, so you probably cannot just edit the Property by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to set the DelegateListLink via Exchange Management Shell. If you retrieve the possible methods en properties for this attribute there is not SetValue-like method:

```
Get-MailboxPermission <mailbox> -ReadFromDomainController)[0].DelegateListLink | Get-Member


TypeName: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
AncestorDN        Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId AncestorDN(int generation)
DescendantDN      Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId DescendantDN(int depth)
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string objString), bool Equals(Microsoft.Ex...
GetAdNameAtDepth  Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.AdName GetAdNameAtDepth(int depth)
GetByteCount      Method     int GetByteCount(System.Text.Encoding encoding)
GetBytes          Method     byte[] GetBytes(), byte[] GetBytes(System.Text.Encoding encoding)
GetChildId        Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId GetChildId(string unescapedCommonName), Mi...
GetDescendantId   Method     Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId GetDescendantId(string unescapedChildName,...
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
IsDescendantOf    Method     bool IsDescendantOf(Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId rootId)
ToCanonicalName   Method     string ToCanonicalName()
ToDNString        Method     string ToDNString()
ToExtendedDN      Method     string ToExtendedDN()
ToGuidOrDNString  Method     string ToGuidOrDNString()
ToString          Method     string ToString()
TraceTo           Method     System.Void TraceTo(Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.ITraceBuilder traceBuilder)
Depth             Property   System.Int32 Depth {get;}
DistinguishedName Property   System.String DistinguishedName {get;}
DomainId          Property   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId DomainId {get;}
IsDeleted         Property   System.Boolean IsDeleted {get;}
IsRelativeDn      Property   System.Boolean IsRelativeDn {get;}
Name              Property   System.String Name {get;}
ObjectGuid        Property   System.Guid ObjectGuid {get;}
Parent            Property   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId Parent {get;}
Rdn               Property   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.AdName Rdn {get;}
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly. That's why I asked ;) However, I got confirmation by Microsoft, that it is indeed impossible to manually set that attribute in Exchange Online.